# Are background images loaded if container opacity is 0

Tags: html, css, browser

Does browser load elements background image if elements opacity is 0?

```
.element {
    background-image: url("someurl");
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: yes if you add that in your HTML :)

Comment: Check your Web Inspector's (or similar tool) Network tab. It should show you that the background image is loaded even if the element's opacity would be set to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome Hit **F12**, Select the **Filter** icon and tick **Images**. This will show you all the images loaded for the current page.

Images like other media such as video and audio are loaded regardless of CSS rules.

It is worth noting as you are hiding your element the available techniques to do so:

`display:none` removes the element from the flow of the document, which causes reflows when you set it back to `display:block`

`visibility:hidden` keeps the element in the flow of the document meaning when you use `visibility:visible` it does not cause a reflow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They're also loaded if they're `display: none;`

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
The browser does load the elements, but their invisible; you can test it with a text selection